# Why do I need parenthesis around print statements even though I'm running python 2.7?

Tags: python, version, jupyter-notebook

I have a jupyter notebook that was written for python 2.7. I'm rerunning this code but for some reason I need parenthesis around my print statements.

I'm deffinately running a python2.7 kernel:
[image]

and yet:
[image]

and [image]

Why do I need parenthesis around print statements even though I'm running python 2.7?

Comment: Any chance `from __future__ import print_function` is part of the config for the ipython kernel (e.g. startup).

Comment: you can restart you kernel or comment out this section in your code `from __future__ import print_fuction`

Comment: I don't know. How would I find out?

Comment: @ZeyadDeeb: they *already* ran that, which is why they now have to use parentheses.

Comment: ipython config includes `exec_lines` in `ipython_kernel_config.py` or it could be included in the startup files - assuming in the `default` profile. On *nix type systems this will be in `$HOME/.ipython/profile_default/startup`

Comment: @CiaranWelsh: the very fact that `print` is a function and not a statement already tells us that you used the `from __future__  import` line somewhere (either directly or in some ipython bootstrapping script).

Comment: Okay, thanks for clearing that up. My worry was that jupyter was somehow switching to python3, which would interfere with the rest of my code. If its just imported from `__future__` it won't impact the rest of my code and I'm safe. Thanks again.